# WPF C#: Prevent Storyboard animation from starting if Panel.Width is already greater than 0

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, data-binding, wpf-controls

Is there a way to prevent the animation from starting if the width is greater than 0. The problem is that when the width is already 250 if the animation starts, it will reset the panel width to 0 then will start the animation.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="Expand">
    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="250" Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DockPanel.Width)" Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=Panel}"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Where do you use the storyboard? Why is it started multiple times?

Comment: @ynsbl, can you provide the related xaml code about the DockPanel and the related screen about your problem? It will be better for us to analyze your problem.